# RejectedExecutionException free threads but full queue

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

What is causing this RejectedExecutionException?

```
[Running, pool size = 40, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 20, completed tasks = 180]
```

ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(30, 40, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
     new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20), threadFactory);
```

Pool size is 40 and only 3 threads are active, so why it is not using rest of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RejectedExecutionException free threads but full queue

This is probably a race condition.  At some point you had added more than 60 tasks to the pool.  40 were running in threads and it went to add the 21st task to the `ArrayBlockingQueue` and it rejected it.  However, when you go back to print out the stats, the jobs have finished so there are only 3 running threads at that moment.

You can add a `RejectedExecutionHandler` handler which will block the producer:

```
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        try {
            // this will block the producer until there's room in the queue
            executor.getQueue().put(r);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RejectedExecutionException(
                "Unexpected InterruptedException", e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I've found the problem. When core threads are started (and not active) and you add a task, the task is then always added to the queue first. So if you add many tasks in a loop it may happen that you reach queue capacity before free threads have a chance to take tasks from queue. So in my case I need to enlarge the queue (to 30) to have the ability to take all tasks added at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the active thread count to debug issues like this. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount%28%29) states that the number is only approximate, and it will be stale by the time you get the `RejectedExecutionException`.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it.