# Parallel java application not receiving CPU to finish task

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a parallel running java application that consumes huge log files and applies some custom logic. Each log row is processed in a separate thread using fire-and-forget approach.

However sometimes the java process just stops processing, what I mean with that is that the java application doesn't get assigned CPU to execute the process even if the application is still hasn't finished consuming the file.

Running ***top*** I get quite low load average considering 16 cores that I have:

[image]

Running **vmstat** I can see that non of the user processes are running neither the kernel processes, rather it's idle 99%

[image]

The output of ***iostat*** shows me that there are no pending IO tasks running either:

[image]

I also haven't spotted any deadlocks or starvation taking a thread dump. The most of the threads are WAITING or RUNNABLE.

What am I missing? I got lost, and I don;t really know where to investigate further.

**=UPDATE=**

This is the part that initiates parallel execution, after this there are thousand lines of code applying modification incl. elasticsearch, akka etc

So I don't really know what the relevant code would be that might causes any troubles.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue =  new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100);
ExecutorService executorService =  new MetricsThreadPoolExecutor(numThreadCore, numThreadCore, idleTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue, new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy(), "process.concurrent", metrics);

FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(fileStream));
String strRow = bufferedReader.readLine();

while (strRow != null) {
    final Row row = new Row(strRow);

    try {
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!StringUtil.isBlank(row.getLine())) {
                    processor.process(row);
                }
            }
        });

        strRow = bufferedReader.readLine();

    } catch (RejectedExecutionException ree) {
        try {
            logger.warn(ree.getMessage());
            Thread.sleep(50L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            logger.warn("Wait interrupted", ie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share the relevant snippets of your code.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have one thread reading the log files, and one thread per log line. You should first check if the main thread gets stuck (use logs for example), and if yes, where (for this use thread dumps).

Comment: @yannick1976 - yes, this is how it works. I will check your suggestion, but yes, I haven't been thinking so easy :)

Comment: Since you did not show how you intialize any variable, you should check their values. Especially `row` should have any value. The easiest solution would be that you have not read the file correctly and `row` is `null`.

Comment: Sounds like a thread got blocked by some IO operation to me, make sure you are reading(if any) files correctly and in a safe manner. for instance calling a wrong IO operation would block the thread

Comment: what is source? if it is scanner, then do not use readLine(). use while (source.hasNext()) first and then call nextLine() or next()

Comment: When you took thread dump, how many threads are running? I don't think system is busy. And catch all possible exception instead of only one type of exception

Comment: Are you sure `row` cannot be `null` in the beginning? I'd probably go with something "safer", like `while ((row = source.readLine()) != null)` instead.

Comment: No row is not null in the beginning. It processes the file and at certain stage (e.g 54%) it dies... I'm using new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)))); as a source. Next I read the row = this.bufferedReader.readLine(); in my while loop..

Comment: updated the code again

Comment: **Off-Topic:** Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However sometimes the java process just stops processing, what I mean with that is that the java application doesn't get assigned CPU to execute the process even if the application is still hasn't finished consuming the file.

Don't think about this at the CPU/vmstat/iostat level.  That's just confusing the debugging of the problem.  You should think about this in terms of threads only and trust the OS to schedule them appropriately.

I see no reason why the main thread shouldn't finish after all of the rows have been submitted for processing.  As an aside, you may instead want to just block the producer instead of regenerating the rows in your spin/sleep loop like you are doing.  See: [RejectedExecutionException free threads but full queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996529/rejectedexecutionexception-free-threads-but-full-queue/22996601#22996601)

If you application is not completing then either one of the worker threads is hung while processing the row or maybe the `MetricsThreadPoolExecutor` has not been shutdown.  I suspect the latter.  The producer thread, after it exits the `while (strRow != null) {` loop should call `executorService.shutdown()`.  Otherwise the threads will be waiting for more rows to be added.

You could do a thread-dump on your application to see if it is stuck in a worker.  You could add logging when the producer thread finishes which should let you know if it completed it's work.  Both might help figure out where the problem lies.